# Honda CRV unknown buttons

Tags: honda, crv

I bought a honda crv 2004, but I can't know what does those buttons stand for in it.

Th rounded button with red border:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The first looks like a button for disabling the window lifters on the rear seats and perhaps the passenger seat. I have the same button on my 2016 Toyota RAV4 hybrid, although it has a better symbol on it. I might be incorrect, though. So you should try the button and see if my guess was correct. Or, it could be related to operating the central locking system.

The third is fog lights, obviously.

Of the second, I do not know unfortunately. Perhaps somebody can come up with a different answer or edit my answer. Could be related to cruise control, but usually there are speed adjustments and other features on the cruise control and this is just one button.

Comment: I think you are correct on all of them and the second button is, imo, the "master on/off" for the cruise - there is probably the set / cancel on the wheel or one of the stalks...

Comment: Most vehicles that have cruise control have a master in/off for the cruise features. Even going back to the early '90s.

Comment: @kyle_engineer most of the newer ones now don't have a master switch as the function is enabled by the ecu based on speed, gear etc

Comment: @SolarMike Really) I've never seen that. My wife's 2017 Accord has a toggle, it's just software based.

Comment: @kyle_engineer My jaguar only has two buttons for resume and cancel and a rotator for increase decrease - the enabling of the cruise is only allowed above 30mph and braking or changing gear cancel it. And it's 2005.

Comment: @SolarMike Interesting. Our Accord has the toggle (which illuminates a dashboard light) then there's "set" (also +), "resume" (also -) and cancel... I think that's all from memory. But as with yours, even when I have toggled the CC on, it won't engage below a given speed (on our it seems like ~25 mph), and pressing the brake will auto-cancel. However, if the dash light for CC is not on (I.e. The CC toggle button hasn't been pressed) you cannot engage anything.

Comment: @kyle_engineer oh and I forgot - if one of the brake light bulbs fails then the cruise won't engage and it's a weird sensing somehow as I fitted LED brake light bulbs which did not draw enough current to trigger the enable. That was "fun" to work out... :)  Also, I think if the traction control comes in due to loss of traction that cancels cruise as well. Good idea if you hit ice.

Comment: @SolarMike That sounds... well, fun and annoying. Lol!

Comment: What is the cruise option about anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Mate I'll make this like icing on top of a super cake.

1. Child lock and window lock enable/disable
2. Cruise control toggler
3. Fog light toggle switch

Comment: source: I have pushed those buttons

Comment: What is the cruise system.anyway ?

Comment: Cruise control module can be toggled 'on' or 'off' from this main toggle switch. To answer your question, further, this system locks the throttle at a certain speed of your desire (which is within the programmed range) for pedal less driving when you Activate it from the steering wheel at the speed you're currently cruising. Before you ask, I don't like it.

Comment: @NumairAidroos - Please quit making your posts (answers) community wikis. There's several reasons why you ***don't*** want to do this. The main reason here is, your posts haven't risen to the level where they deserve to be wikis.If you have questions/concerns, please hit me up on [**The Pitstop**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop), this site's chat page.